# Why is my $PATH different in the executed script?

Tags: zsh

echo $PATH inside gnome terminal:

> /home/pc/less.js/bin:/home/pc/local/bin:/home/pc/local/bin:/home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin:/home/pc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-head@global/bin:/home/pc/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/bin:/home/pc/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/pc/local/bin:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/home/pc/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin:/home/pc/Programming/Software/tup:/home/pc/Programming/Libraries/depottools:/home/pc/Programming/Libraries/apache-maven-3.0.4/bin

From inside this script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo $PATH
while inotifywait -e modify /home/pc/vbox-shared/less; do
    lessc custom.less > /home/pc/vbox-shared/less/custom.css
done
```

> /usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/home/pc/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin

As you can see, I modified my `.zshrc` file with this:

> export PATH=/home/pc/less.js/bin:$PATH

Why does it not work in the script when executed as a file? The problem is that the lessc command is not being found.

Comment: Somewhat relevant answer: https://superuser.com/a/994311/135762

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The script is run using `/bin/zsh`, which is not an interactive or login shell and doesn't load this file. From `man zsh`, emphasis mine:

> Commands are first read from /etc/zshenv; this cannot be overridden.  Subsequent behaviour is modified by the RCS and GLOBAL_RCS options; the former affects all startup files, while the second  only  affects global  startup  files  (those shown here with an path starting with a /).  If one of the options is unset at any point, any subsequent startup file(s) of the corresponding type will not be read.  It is also possible for a file in $ZDOTDIR to re-enable GLOBAL_RCS. Both RCS and GLOBAL_RCS are set by default.
>
> Commands are then read from $ZDOTDIR/.zshenv.  **If the shell is a login shell, commands are read from /etc/zprofile and then $ZDOTDIR/.zprofile.  Then, if the shell is  interactive,  commands  are  read  from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc**.  Finally, if the shell is a login shell, /etc/zlogin and $ZDOTDIR/.zlogin are read.

The script inherits the environment from where it's called, and if this isn't another (interactive) shell, it won't contain the preferences you set in `.zshrc`.

You can set the `PATH` where it applies globally (e.g. `/etc/zshenv`), set it explicitly in the script directly, or change the shebang script header to run `/bin/zsh -i` instead, making it load `.zshrc` (quoting `man zsh`: *Force shell to be interactive.  It is still possible to specify a script to execute.*).

Alternatively, just specify the full path to the program that isn't on the default `PATH`, e.g. `/home/pc/less.js/bin/lessc`.

Answer (score 1):

zsh startup files (a.k.a. rc files)

A filename below that is not a full path is implicitly preceded by “$ZDOTDIR/”, which is typically your home directory.

The order in which zsh sources startup script files is as follows.

**/etc/zshenv** – First, commands are read from here; options cannot be override this.

**.zshenv**

**/etc/zprofile** – login shell

**.zprofile** – login shell

**/etc/zshrc** – interactive shell

**.zshrc** – interactive shell

**/etc/zlogin** – login shell

**.zlogin** – login shell

Two zsh options affect whether zsh sources certain of the above files. (“RCS” is the plural of “rc”, rendered in upper case.)

RCS and GLOBAL_RCS zsh options are set by default.

- RCS – affects all startup files
- GLOBAL_RCS – affects only global startup files (pathnames starting with “/”)

If a startup file unsets one of these options, zsh skips subsequent startup files of the that type.

If a startup file sets the GLOBAL_RCS option, zsh sources subsequent global startup files.