# Why doesn't zsh autoload work in a script?

Tags: zsh

I am trying to get to grips with autoloading functions in zsh. I have added the folder in which I'm storing my functions (~/.zfuncs) to my fpath, and I've added a test function

```
# ~/.zfuncs/myfunction
echo "Hello world!"
```

This works fine when I autoload it in my console:

```
stephanie% autoload -Uz myfunction
stephanie% myfunction
Hello world!
```

When I try to run it in a script this doesn't work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# ~/scripts/test-myfunction.sh

autoload -Uz myfunction
myfunction
```

Running the script produces an error:

```
stephanie% zsh ~/scripts/test-myfunction.sh
myfunction:5: myfunction: function definition file not found
```

It works if I add the following line to the start of the script:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, with information from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/417711/why-is-my-path-different-in-the-executed-script) answer. I needed to have the line adding my folder to fpath in my .zshenv file, not my .zshrc file, because when it's a script it's not an interactive shell.